# Error: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value I/flutter (18363): 'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':

Tags: flutter

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nX0PJ.png)
Hi I'm new to flutter and have a question about dropdownbutton regarding using the same values for multiple dropdownbutton.

From my understanding from the error, it was due to using the same list for 2 or more dropdownbuttons in the same activity.

How am i able to resolve this error but still able to reuse the list for 2 or more dropdownbuttons?

```
  String _value1;
  String _value2;

  final List<String> nameList = <String>[
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3",
    "Name4",
    "Name5",
    "Name6",
    "Name7",
    "Name8"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2.0,
        title: Text('Hello'),
      ),
      body:  ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Name: '),
                  Center(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      value: _value1,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value1 = value;
                        });
                      },
                      items: nameList.map(
                        (item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item,
                            child: new Text(item),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Name: '),
                  Center(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      value: _value2,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value2 = value;
                        });
                      },
                      items: nameList.map(
                        (item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item,
                            child: new Text(item),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting this problem even though I can prove that the `DropdownMenuItem` with the key is only instantiated once. I'm spent days trying to work this one out.

Comment: I have no explanations for this behaviour, but just remove the value attribute and you are good to go.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I had the exact same error, multiple Dropdowns all feeding from the same static list, the only difference is that in my case, it was a list of Objects, not Strings.

So, if it's a static list, there's no way it's empty, no duplicate values in the list, AND you already make sure `value` is not empty? Then the only option remaining is that `item.value` is different than `value`

In my case, as it was an Object list, I had to overwrite `operator ==` and `hashcode` methods in my Object class.

```
bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other != null && other is TimeSelection && this.hour == other.hour;

  @override
  int get hashCode => super.hashCode;
```

And that was it. I didn't had to initialize `_value1` or `_value2`

Comment: This should be marked as an accepted answer. Adding the equality and hashCode functions solved the issue for me. I was passing an object from one page to another and it happened that the instance of the one being passed into the new page is different from the one created from the list in the new page, even though they were all constructed from the same data.

Comment: I created a copy of my list of objects, and I marked this new list as final. It worked fine

Comment: Agreed. I had the same issue, single list using custom objects, I followed the above and overrode == and hashcode within my custom object, worked a champ.

Comment: @MonstersX can you please share the code on how you did add override === and hashcode into your custom object

Comment: If you have a lot of classes that needs this, checkout the Equatable package https://pub.dev/packages/equatable it makes it more easy.

Comment: @user3551487 I put this within my custom object (group in my case, wanted unique by name).         
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) =>
      other != null && other is Group && this.name == other.name;

Comment: I have a class used for the dropdown button menu item.  I want to find in the dropdownmenuitem the item for a specific class object.  when I initialize the variable with the class and assign it as a value to the dropdownbutton, I get an error that it is zero or 2.   Can you explain how hash would fix this problem?

Comment: return DropdownMenuItem<MyClass>(
              value: item, child: Text(item.displayValue));
        })

Comment: Works like charm. In my case i had a custom object `CarColor` with two member variables- a `String colorName` and a `Color color` with values assigned in the constructor of my custom Object. my two overrides as @David_E had answered were `@override bool operator ==(dynamic other) => other != null && other is CarColor && colorName == other.colorName && color == other.color` and `@override int get hashCode => super.hashCode`

Comment: I have the same error. how to use it? when I use these 2 lines of code, I face to Error. and the error is TimeSelection isn't a type.

Answer (score 24):

You are getting that exception because _value1 and _value2 aren't initialized and providing empty to the dropdown widget.

You could do something like this:

```
DropdownButton(
  value: _value1.isNotEmpty ? _value1 : null, // guard it with null if empty
  items: nameList.map((item) {
           return DropdownMenuItem(
              value: item,
              child: new Text(item),
           );
         }).toList(), 
);
```

Answer (score 12):

This exception you have because of mistakes:

1. No `_value1` and `_value2` initialization.
2. When you initialize them make sure that `_value1` and `_value2` right from `nameList` e.g.

```
_value1 = nameList[0];
_value2 = nameList[3];
```

this is important step with complex data type, but in your case

```
_value1 = "Name1";
_value2 = "Name4";
```

will be sufficient.

Full example:

```
  String _value1;
  String _value2;

  final List<String> nameList = <String>[
    "Name1",
    "Name2",
    "Name3",
    "Name4",
    "Name5",
    "Name6",
    "Name7",
    "Name8"
  ];

  /// initialization is here:
  @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _value1 = nameList[0];
    _value2 = nameList[3];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Name: '),
            Center(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: _value1,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value1 = value;
                  });
                },
                items: nameList.map(
                  (item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: new Text(item),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Name: '),
            Center(
              child: DropdownButton(
                value: _value2,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _value2 = value;
                  });
                },
                items: nameList.map(
                  (item) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: new Text(item),
                    );
                  },
                ).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem, and I solved it.
The dropdown button needs items list and value. We define items and selected items, but the item chosen instance does not inside the items list.

You should try this and fix your logic.
(value ıs selected item value for user)

```
 var _value = itemList.isEmpty
    ? value
    : itemList.firstWhere((item) => item.value == value.value);
```

More : https://gist.github.com/VB10/fd560694fec0a38751e798a213408001

Answer (score 7):

You must initialise the `_value1` and `_value2` and make sure those values are also present in `nameList`.

Comment: One key thing is to make sure those values are also present in nameList. That solved mine

Comment: Simple and valid!

Comment: so simple and yet so useful!

Answer (score 5):

My solution was more simple than every one else. The fact that was find a value that wasn't the same as in the list, is because I have put a **value** in the variable, that wasn't either full or empty, the value was this ("") and it has to be **null** for the Dropdown value instance. So, I just have put a value null in the declaration of variable. like: "String _value;", and voila, it worked.

#Sorry for the English, Brazilian here.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use `FormBuilderDropdown` of the package *[flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder)*.
Adding `key: UniqueKey()` in the Widget `FormBuilderDropdown` is the solution for my case.

Comment: This worked for me, I also had that problem with that package.

Comment: but there onChanged() method not given for this plugin

Comment: @s.j The method onChanged() also provided in this package.

Comment: I'm updated a DropDownButtonFormField from another DropDownButton and setting a key worked well for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue with Getx package. When it's updated, it causes this error because add same items to list. Adding `key: UniqueKey()` to `DropdownButtonFormField` is the solution for me.

Comment: Hey mate, Thanks for the answer but can you share the sample code because I am facing the same issue while working with the GetX package. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2):

You must initialise the `_value1` and `_value2` with a initial Value.

Answer (score 2):

`_value1` and `_value2` variables need to be initialized, or you can do that:

```
value: _value1 != null ? _value1 : null,
hint: Text('Your hint'),
```

Answer (score 2):

var _issues = [
"Subscription Related",
"Talk Therapy Related",
"Program Related",
"Account Related",
"Technology Related",
];

String _currentSelectedValue=_issues.first;

Answer (score 2):

As much as the answer accepted may be working, it is unnecessary and over achieving.

All you need to do is ENSURE THAT whatever your initialized the value to is in the list as well. That is:

String _value1 = "Name1";

If the initialized value is not in your list, you will get the error message you are getting. Period!

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your code is right then do "hot restart" instead of "hot reload".

Answer (score 2):

If you Have Depeneted Dropdownlist and dynamic List Just simpy Clear list value and make value null on Onchnage Method

```
  onChanged: ( value) {
                      setState(() {
                        regionName = value;
                           _city.clear();
                           CityName=null;
                            CityList();
                          print(regionName);
                      });
                    },
```

Answer (score 1):

this solved in my case

```
value: _value1,
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        _value1 = value;
        _value2 = null;
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

The dropdownbuttonformfield filtering mechanism uses a single field for filtering.  It can not filter by class hash.  Set the DropdownMenuItem value to the key of the incoming data.  The dropdownmenuItem value must be unique.   The key is String type.  currentStatus holds the key to position in the dropdown.  I map a list of class objects where the class has databaseValue field and a displayValue field to the dropdownmenuitem as value:databaseValue and child:Text(displayValue).  Now, I can set _currentStatus to a databaseValue and it will position in the dropdown.

```
String _currentStatus;

List<DropdownMenuItem> listMenuItems =
  <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[];

Provider.of<Api>(context, listen: false)
    .getComboViews()
    .then((data) {
  setState(() {
    listMenuItems =
        data.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: item.databaseValue, child: Text(item.displayValue));
    }).toList();


 DropdownButtonFormField<String>( 
     value: this._currentStatus,
     items: listMenuItems
     onChanged: (String value) {
           setState(() {
           this._currentStatus = value;
    });
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String? dropdownValue
 hint: Text( "Select City"),
  value: dropdownValue == null ? null : dropdownValue,


onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        dropdownValue = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>[
                      'Islamabad',
                      'RawalPindi',
                      'Mangla',
                      'Mirpur'
                    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have Multiple DropDownButtons which are dependent on one another.
Adding  key: (_value1 != null)
? Key(_value1)
: UniqueKey() to the dependent DropdownButtonFormField

```
children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Name: '),
                  Center(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      value: _value1,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value1 = value;
                        });
                      },
                      items: nameList.map(
                        (item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item,
                            child: new Text(item),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Name: '),
                  Center(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                      value: _value2,
                      key: (_value1 != null) ? Key(_value1) : UniqueKey()
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _value2 = value;
                        });
                      },
                      items: nameList.map(
                        (item) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: item,
                            child: new Text(item),
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
```

Answer (score 1):

The default value should be present in the list will get the job done.

Here is the example code that might help:

```
    List<String> models = [
  'ChatGPT0',
  'ChatGPT1',
  'ChatGPT2',
  'ChatGPT3',
  'ChatGPT4',
];

  String currentModel = 'ChatGPT0';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      dropdownColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      items: getModelsItem,
      value: currentModel,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          if (currentModel.isNotEmpty) {
            currentModel = value.toString();
          }
        });
      },
    );
```

where getModelsItem is the getter function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same list in multiple `DropDownButton`. The error you got is because of having more than one same values in the list. 
For Example, if I change the list to given below where I have two items having the same value, it will throw me an error.

```
`final List<String> nameList = <String>[
    "Name1",
    "Name1",
    "Name3",
    "Name4",
    "Name5",
    "Name6",
    "Name7",
    "Name8"
  ];`
```

Error: 
  [image]

Comment: Hmm but for my case, I have made sure the values are unique inside the list, but thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

**_value1** and **_value2** must be in your list

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by specifying the type (in my case String): `FormBuilderDropdown<String>` and setting `initialValue: null`
I have Flutter 3.3.4

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the `value` field type is not the same than the types used in `items`. Here is a example throwing the same error.

```
FittedBox(
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          child: DropdownButton<E>(
            //isExpanded: true,
            value: box?.get(hiveKey), // hive key = string value --> need to convert to E type
            onChanged: (final E? newValue) {
              updateSettingsOnTap(box);
            },
            items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<E>>((E value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<E>( // --> E type not string
                value: value.item,
                child: Text(value.getItemValue(), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
              );
            }).toList(),
```

You have to use the same type in value and items fields to fix it. Working code below.

```
 child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.contain,
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
                //isExpanded: true,
                value: box?.get(hiveKey), 
                onChanged: (final String? newValue) {
                  updateSettingsOnTap(box);
                },
                items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis), 
                  );
                }).toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have implemented the dropdowns. This code handles exceptions in case list is not loaded or preselected value does not exist in the list. Also, it does provide validation on selected item.

Following is the Widget implementation ( e.g. froonodropdown.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FroonoDropDown<T> extends FormField<T> {
  final T? selectedValue;
  final FocusNode? fnNode;
  final void Function(T) onChanged;
  final List<T> list;
  final String Function(T) getLabel;
  final String label;

  FroonoDropDown(this.label, this.list, this.selectedValue, this.fnNode, this.onChanged, this.getLabel, {Key? key})
      : super(
          key: key,
          validator: (T? item) {
            return item == null ? "Please choose an option" : null;
          },
          initialValue: list.contains(selectedValue) ? selectedValue : null,
          builder: (FormFieldState<T> state) {
            List<DropdownMenuItem<T>> dropdownItems = [];
            dropdownItems.add(DropdownMenuItem(value: null, child: Text("Select " + label)));

            //handle exception in case list is not loaded or selectedValue is not part of the list
            T? defaultValue = selectedValue;
            if (selectedValue != null && !list.contains(selectedValue)) {
              if (getLabel(selectedValue).isEmpty) {
                defaultValue = null;
              } else {
                list.add(selectedValue);
              }
            }

            dropdownItems.addAll(list.map((T item) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: item,
                child: Text(getLabel(item)),
              );
            }).toList());

            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InputDecorator(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: label),
                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                    child: DropdownButton(
                        focusNode: fnNode,
                        value: defaultValue,
                        isDense: true,
                        onChanged: (T? selectedItem) {
                          state.didChange(selectedItem);
                          if (selectedItem != null) onChanged(selectedItem);
                        },
                        items: dropdownItems),
                  ),
                ),
                if (state.hasError)
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(state.errorText!, style: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(state.context).errorColor, fontSize: 12)),
                  )
              ],
            );
          },
        );
}
```

Examples:
With String items:

```
FroonoDropDown<String>("String Items", stringItemsList, defaultValue, null, (String value) {
                        defaultValue = value;
                         //do something else with value;
                      }, (String item) => item)
```

With any custom class:

```
FroonoDropDown<CustomClass>("My Custom List", customClassObjsList,
defaultValue, null, (CustomClass value) {
                  defaultValue = value;   
                  //do something else with value;
                }, (CustomClass act) => act.title)
```

Make sure you override comparison operator and hashcode in your CustomClass, like this:

```
  @override
  bool operator ==(dynamic other) {
    return other != null && typeid == other.typeid;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => super.hashCode;
```

I hope above implementation would be useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions above might be fix for some people.
For me, is about form reset value of the dependent fields.

```
void onCountryChange() {
    ...
    formKey.currentState!.fields['city']!.reset();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error and it was driving me crazy. I didn't have duplicate objects, and my selected value matched a value in my list.

I was using an object in my dropdown and instead of setting the value like this:

```
value: _selectedObject,
```

I had to set it like this to make it work:

```
value: snapshot.data.firstWhere((object) => object.id == _selectedObject?.id),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have 2 dropDownFormField and one depends on the other to capture the API information. I forced the cleaning of one of the fields so that there was not this problem.

I did something like this:

In my first DropDown (Deposito), I defined in onTap:

```
child: DropdownButtonFormField<Deposito?>(
            onTap: () {
              listaLocalizacao.clear();
              localizacaoSelecionada = null;
            },
```

listaLocazicao would be your nameList, so in this case I cleared the list and set localizacaoSelecionada is null, localizacaoSelecionada is your _value1, so I just cleared the data from the second dropDownButton.

I hope I helped someone who is having the problem with some dropDownButton that depends on the information of the other to present the options.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the dropdown list items from the API so the list was empty when the dropdown was visually built then the data came and now the values are different from it was firstly passed to the dropdown the solution is to make sure that you have your list data before the UI is build.