# Initializing dropdownbutton in correct place in flutter code

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use this dropdown menu that has a list populated from a QuerySnapshot. I think I have it all set up right but it is causing this error:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
```

I think this error has to do with the initialization of the Dropdown.

This is where I set the initial state of the dropdown. I assign the value from a document if it exists:

```
setState(() {
          _selectedInspectorCompany =
              trxnSnapshot.data()?['inspectorCompanyId'] ?? "";
        });
```

This is the code for the dropdown.

```
Wrap(

      children: [
        const Text(
          'Inspector Company:    ',
        ),
        StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _db.collection('inspectorCompany').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> inspectorCompanyItems =
                [];
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final inspectorCompanyList = snapshot.data!.docs;
              for (var inspectorCompany in inspectorCompanyList) {
                inspectorCompanyItems.add(
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: inspectorCompany.id,
                    child: Text(
                      inspectorCompany['inspectorCompanyName'],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              return DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: const Text("Select Inspector"),
                value: _selectedInspectorCompany,
                onChanged: (inspectorCompanyValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedInspectorCompany =
                        inspectorCompanyValue;
                  });
                  ref
                      .read(trxnNotifierProvider.notifier)
                      .updateInspectorCompanyId(
                          _selectedInspectorCompany!);
                },
                items: inspectorCompanyItems,
              );
            } else {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

I think I am doing this correct but why am I getting the error?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**
If I add an inspectorCompany id to the transaction document so that it matches one of the inspectorCompany ids in the list of inspector companies it works fine.

**What am I doing wrong?** I think it may have to do with how I am initializing the _selectedInspectorCompany variable in the first code snippet but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is what the code looks like now:

```
String? _selectedInspectorCompany;

_selectedInspectorCompany = null;

return DropdownButton<String>(
                            hint: const Text("Select Inspector"),
                            value: _selectedInspectorCompany ??
                                inspectorCompanyItems[0].toString(),
```

Comment: Can you please share more details about your `inspectorCompanyItems` List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the initial value of `_selectedInspectorCompany` is empty or null. Make it null when you initialise and try adding a null check and assign the first value like the following

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
                hint: const Text("Select Inspector"),
                value: _selectedInspectorCompany??inspectorCompanyList[0].id,
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am still getting the same error. I will show what I did in the original post.

Comment: Sorry i used the wrong variable. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you have is because you have more than one value in the list. checks if there is a repeating value in the list that the DropdownButton loads.

```
final List<String> myList = <String>[
    "juan1",
    "juan1",
    "pedro3"
  ];
```

Comment: but if not that you should check if you initialize the variable correctly. I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not have duplicate items. I initialize it in the first code snippet. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: `_selectedInspectorCompany` How do you initialize it? maybe there is the problem check this forum [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59925233/either-zero-or-2-or-more-dropdownmenuitems-were-detected-with-the-same-value)