# Flutter: Prevent executed feturebuilder when setState is occurred

Tags: flutter, async-await

I am trying to load DropDownMenu inside Future builder.In my widget i have a Column. Inside Column I have a few widget :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(),
        Divider(),
        Container(),
        ...widget._detailsModel.data.appletActions.map((item) {
            .....
            ...item.appletInputs.map((inputs) {
                             FutureBuilder(
                                future: MyToolsProvider()
                                    .getDropDownConfiges(inputs.dataUrl),
                                builder: 
                                (ctx,AsyncSnapshot<DropDownModel.DropDownConfigToolsModle>snapshot) {
                                  if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                                      snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                    return Center(
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                    );
                                  }
                                  if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                      snapshot.connectionState ==
                                          ConnectionState.done) {
                                         _dropDown = snapshot.data.data[0];   
                                    return DropdownButton<DropDownModel.DataModle>(
                                      hint: Text("Select Item"),
                                      value: _dropDown,
                                      onChanged: (data) {

                                        setState(() {
                                          _dropDown = data;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      items: snapshot.data.data.map((item) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<
                                            DropDownModel.DataModle>(
                                          value: item,
                                          child: Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Icon(Icons.title),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                width: 10,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                item.title,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      }).toList(),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return Center(
                                      child: Text('failed to load'),
                                    );
                                  }
                                }),
                   }
       }
]
```

As you can see i have FutureBuilder inside a loop to show `DropdownButton`.everything is ok and code works as a charm but my problem is :

```
  onChanged: (data) {
   setState(() {
    _dropDown = data;
   })
```

every time `setState` called, `future: MyToolsProvider().getDropDownConfiges(inputs.dataUrl),` is executed and 
_dropDown = snapshot.data.data[0]; again initialized and it get back in a first time .

It is not possible declared `MyToolsProvider().getDropDownConfiges(inputs.dataUrl),` in initState() method because `inputs.dataUrl` it is not accessible there.

How can i fixed that?

Comment: You should still use initState (and potentially didChangeDependencies + didUpdateWidget)

Comment: what about `AsyncMemoizer`?

Comment: I do not know about `AsyncMemoizer` @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating parent state from within a builder is anti-pattern here. To reduce future errors and conflicts I recommend to wrap the parts that use and update _dropDown variable as a statefull widget.

Afterward the builder is just responsible of selecting correct widget based on future results and separated widget will **only** update itself based on interactions. Then hopefully many current and potential errors will disappear.

Comment: Anytime buddy 

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing, change this
`_dropDown = snapshot.data.data[0];`
to 
`_dropDown ??= snapshot.data.data[0];`
What this will do is, it will check if _dropDown is null then assign it with value otherwise it won't.

Comment: I got this error `DataModle _dropDown
package:mobile_iotel/screens/user/config_tools_screen.dart
Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.
Try changing the condition.d` @jagrajsingh

Comment: Pardon, it's ??= Operator not ?=

Comment: I got this error https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/TkczBH9HDV/  @JagrajSingh

Comment: Could you please post the full code ? Also try removing the assignment line and check if it works or not.

Comment: this is complete code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xGJtgMfKbg/ @JagrajSingh

Comment: The code seems fine to me. The error says that _dropDown has more or less values than 1. Try printing the _dropDown value in build function and see how many time value gets changed and check if you have assigned it more than once or not.

Comment: I debug and it just called twice. once futurebuilder get drop down from server and other when user change the drop down item that is caused set state called.@JagrajSingh

Comment: Yes, i still got https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f28SpRd8Nj/  @JagrajSingh

Comment: Ok! I got this. You have to initialize the _dropDown. You can simply put ```_dropDown =null``` in the waiting state of the future builder. Reference :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474307/error-either-zero-or-2-or-more-dropdownmenuitems-were-detected-with-the-same

Comment: you mean here : `class _LoadConfigScreenState extends State<LoadConfigScreen> {
  DropDownModel.DataModle _dropDown = null;` @JagrajSingh

Comment: Yes you can do that too or just assign it in the FuturBuilder's ConnectionState.waiting

Comment: I changed code to this https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/R2YcjDQhK6/ but still got problem @JagrajSingh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209691/discussion-between-jagraj-singh-and-sayres-kabir).