# Why DropdownButtonFormField Wrapped with FutureBuilder Being Rebuilt with Same Data Appended?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a Flutter stateless dropdown widget that is dependent on some future list, I used the `FutureBuilder` to build the dropdown as soon as the future is resolved.

But I noticed that `build` method was being called at least twice. I know it is normal that the `build` method can be called multiple times when some state changes, but why was the dropdown was being rebuilt with the same data as the previous `build` call? I thought for sure when `build` is called, Flutter will rebuild the entire widget which also implies that the previous data will be destroyed as well.

This has resulted in duplication in the items of the dropdown.

[image]

I am not sure why it is happening. What did I miss?

```dart
class _PetTypeInput extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final petTypes = context.read<RegisterPetProfileCubit>().getPetTypes();

    return FutureBuilder<List<PetType>>(
      future: petTypes,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<PetType>> snapshot) {
        List<PetType>? petKinds = [];

        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          petKinds = snapshot.data;

          return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
            key: const Key('registerForm_petKindInput_dropdownButtonFormField'),
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'pet kind',
              helperText: '',
              errorText: null,
            ),
            value: 'Dog',
            onChanged: (petKindValue) => context
                .read<RegisterPetProfileCubit>()
                .petKindChanged(petKindValue!),
            items: _buildItems(petKinds),
          );
        }

        return const TextField(
          enabled: false,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: 'pet kind',
            helperText: '',
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _buildItems(List<PetType>? petKinds) {
    final petTypes = petKinds!.fold(
      <String, String>{},
      (Map<String, String> petTypesMap, petType) {
        petTypesMap[petType.id] = petType.label;
        return petTypesMap;
      },
    );

    List<String> items = petTypes.keys.toList();

    return items.map((key) {
      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        key: Key(key),
        child: Text(petTypes[key]!),
        value: key,
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

I can definitely tell that there are no duplicates in the data.

[image]

How do I prevent appending the same data? Or clear the previous data of `DropdownButtonFormField`?

Comment: can you share  response data-String of `snapshot.data;`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh there in the last screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The issue is not duplicate dropdown items but rather my initial value is not a valid value. My initial value was `Dog` when it should be the id of the `Dog` item.

So I grabed the first item object and then grabed the id of that item and supplied it as initial value.

[image]

The answers from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474307/error-either-zero-or-2-or-more-dropdownmenuitems-were-detected-with-the-same/65663004) helped me figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can build `_buildItems(petKinds),` before `return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(` and passing item[0] value on  `DropdownButtonFormField  value`. And it will make sure the value contain on DropDownMenuItems. Also, make sure to have Unique value on each DropDownMenuItem.

Comment: I don't think it is missing. Look at the fold call of the list, it will actually create a map with the `id` as the  `key` partnered with `label` as a value.

Comment: Is there any duplicate value on response? like having `Dog`  more than one?

Comment: Thanks your suggestion kinda helped me, but I eventually arrived on my own solution.