# flutter error: Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am using two dropdowns. My dropdowns will be work alternate, We select city from first dropdown after selecting city I will get outlets then I will show outlets.

For the first time its working fine but after selected both when i change my city then I am getting error for outlet.

When both dropdowns are selected if I will go to change my city then I want my outlet data cleared so i can choose another outlet.

This is my error

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButtonFormField]'s value: Instance of 'OutletList'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1223 pos 11: 'items == null ||
              items.isEmpty ||
              value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                    return item.value == value;
                  }).length ==
                  1'
```

this is my code

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'dart:ui';

import '../../BlocPages/CubitPage/OutletCubit/outlet_cubit.dart';
import '../../BlocPages/CubitPage/OutletCubit/outlet_state.dart';
import '../../Models/outlet_city_list_model.dart';
import '../../Models/outlet_list_model.dart';
import '../ConstantsPages/toast_page.dart';
import '../GlobalColor/global_color.dart';
import '../GlobalTextStyles/global_text_styles.dart';
import '../GlobalWidgetPages/center_text_with_container.dart';
import '../GlobalWidgetPages/double_btn_in_single_row.dart';

class OutletDialogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<OutletCityListModel> data;

  const OutletDialogPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
    required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<OutletDialogPage> createState() => _OutletDialogPageState();
}

class _OutletDialogPageState extends State<OutletDialogPage> {
  List<OutletCityListModel> cityList = [];
  List<OutletList> outletList = [];
  String outletAddress = "";
  String outletName = "";
  List<OutletListModel>? selectedData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print(selectedData);
    print("my data ${widget.data.length}");
    super.initState();
    cityList = widget.data.toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      insetPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: dialogContent(context),
    );
  }
}

double t4Size = 14;

extension widgetExtension on _OutletDialogPageState {
  dialogContent(BuildContext context) {
    return BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.3, sigmaY: 3.3),
      child: Dialog(
        insetPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 0, right: 0),
        shape:
            RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
        // backgroundColor: skyBlue,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Container(
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: MyColor.whiteColor,
                shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: MyColor.blackColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                    blurRadius: 10.0,
                    offset: const Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: MyColor.primaryRedColor,
                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: CenterTextWithContainer(txt: "${widget.title}"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 23.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0),
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                            itemSplashColor: MyColor.lightBlueColor,
                            itemHeight: 36,
                            itemHighlightColor: MyColor.greyColor2,
                            dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                            dropdownPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                            selectedItemHighlightColor: MyColor.lightBlueColor,

                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              ),
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            isExpanded: true,
                            hint: Row(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  height: 18,
                                  width: 18,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                        'assets/outline_location_pin.png'),
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                  )),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 4,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Select City',
                                    style: textStyleWith12400(
                                        MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                              color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                            ),
                            //   iconOnClick: Icon(
                            //   Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                            //   color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                            // ),
                            iconSize: 22,
                            buttonHeight: 44,
                            buttonPadding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 12),
                            dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            items: cityList
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<OutletCityListModel>>(
                                    (OutletCityListModel option) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: option,
                                  child: Text(
                                    option.city.toString(),
                                    style:
                                        textStyleWith12400(MyColor.blackColor),
                                  ));
                            }).toList(),
                            selectedItemBuilder: (con) {
                              return cityList.map<Widget>((item) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      height: 18,
                                      width: 18,
                                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                          image: DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            'assets/outline_location_pin.png'),
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 4,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${item.city}",
                                        style: textStyleWith12400(
                                            MyColor.blackColor),
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              }).toList();
                            },
                            onChanged: (OutletCityListModel? value) {
                              print("cities:: " + value.toString());
                              setState(() {
                                outletList.clear();
                                selectedData = null;
                                outletName = "";
                                outletAddress = "";
                                outletList = value!.outletList!;
                                print("outletList:: " + outletList.length.toString());
                              });
                              //Do something when changing the item if you want.
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 12.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 0),
                          child: DropdownButtonFormField2(
                            itemSplashColor: MyColor.lightBlueColor,
                            itemHeight: 36,
                            itemHighlightColor: MyColor.greyColor2,
                            dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                            dropdownPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2, right: 2),
                            selectedItemHighlightColor: MyColor.lightBlueColor,

                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    BorderSide(color: MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              ),
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                              ),
                            ),
                            isExpanded: true,
                            hint: Row(
                              children: [
                                Image.asset(
                                  "assets/current_outlet_icon.png",
                                  height: 14.81,
                                  width: 18,
                                  color: MyColor.greyColor,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 4,
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Select Outlet',
                                    style: textStyleWith12400(
                                        MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                              color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                            ),
                            //   iconOnClick: Icon(
                            //   Icons.arrow_drop_up,
                            //   color: MyColor.darkGreyColor,
                            // ),
                            iconSize: 22,
                            buttonHeight: 44,
                            buttonPadding:
                                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 12),
                            dropdownDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                            ),
                            items: outletList
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<OutletList>>((option) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: option,
                                  child: Text(
                                    option.title.toString(),
                                    style:
                                        textStyleWith12400(MyColor.blackColor),
                                  ));
                            }).toList(),
                            selectedItemBuilder: (con) {
                              return outletList.map<Widget>((item) {
                                return Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Image.asset(
                                      "assets/current_outlet_icon.png",
                                      height: 14.81,
                                      width: 18,
                                      color: MyColor.greyColor,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 4,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "${item.title}",
                                        style: textStyleWith12400(
                                            MyColor.blackColor),
                                        maxLines: 1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                );
                              }).toList();
                            },
                            onChanged: (OutletList? value) {
                              print("outlet" + value!.toJson().toString());
                              setState(() {
                                selectedData = [OutletListModel.fromJson(value.toJson())];
                                outletName = "${value.title}";
                                outletAddress = "${value.address}";
                                print("selectedData $selectedData");
                              });
                              //Do something when changing the item if you want.
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 21.0, left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30),
                          child: Container(
                            // height: 134,
                            child: outletAddress == ""
                                ? Container()
                                : Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Outlet Address",
                                        style: textStyleWith16600(
                                            MyColor.blackColor),
                                      ),
                                      SizedBox(
                                        height: 16,
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                            top: 15.0,
                                            left: 12,
                                            right: 12,
                                            bottom: 13),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: MyColor.whiteColor,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color: MyColor.greyColor
                                                  .withOpacity(0.3),
                                              blurRadius: 3.0,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        child: Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Padding(
                                                  padding:
                                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                                                  child: Image.asset(
                                                    "assets/current_outlet_icon.png",
                                                    height: 15,
                                                    width: 17.30,
                                                    color: MyColor.blueColor,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  width: 8,
                                                ),
                                                Expanded(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    "$outletName",
                                                    style: textStyleWith14500(
                                                        MyColor.blackColor),
                                                    maxLines: 1,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "$outletAddress",
                                              style: textStyleWith10400(
                                                  MyColor.darkGreyColor),
                                              maxLines: 3,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  DoubleBtnInSingleRow(
                    cancelOnPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    cancelText: "CANCEL",
                    successText: "SUBMIT",
                    successOnPressed: () {
                      print("selectedData $selectedData");
                      if (selectedData != null) {
                        BlocProvider.of<OutletCubit>(context)
                            .emit(OutletCodeSentState(selectedData!));
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      } else {
                        showToastWithBlackColor(
                            "Please select your city and outlet.");
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59474307/error-either-zero-or-2-or-more-dropdownmenuitems-were-detected-with-the-same

Comment: try `cityList = widget.data.toSet().List();`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed `value` parameter in `DropdownButtonFormField2`.

So try to add it like that

```
value: selectedData,
```